# How does an Abstract Subclass work in Java?

Tags: java, abstract-class

Could we have a concrete superclass and then an abstract subclass? Could someone please explain how that works?

Thank You

Comment: Why don't you just try it out? I don't see why this should not be possible.

Comment: You can create a class and extend it and name the subclass as abstract class. Write some system.out.println statements in both of them. Decide which class instance you can create and check what is the output. IF you have doubts there, feel free to ask and we will help you

Comment: We can but shouldn't.

Comment: @BheshGurung: Really? Given that `java.lang.Object` is a concrete class, I can't see how you can avoid it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This already happens everywhere because all classes inherit directly or indirectly from `Object`. So for example `AbstractCollection` is an abstract class which inherits from the concrete class `Object`.

There is nothing particularly special about this. Concrete subclasses of the abstract class still have to implement the abstract methods.

Answer (score 2):

You can have it yes. The only constraints about a class being abstract is that:

1. When inherited, the abstract methods must be implemented or the inherited class must be abstract as well.
2. It can't be instantiated

Since abstract classes can have implemented methods then you can use the methods of the non-abstract super class when defining methods in the abstract class. Additionally, whoever inherits from the abstract class gets the methods from the non-abstract super class, like this:

Vehicle inherits Abstract Car inherits Ferrari

Then Ferrari would get the actual implemented methods of vehicle.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, and as long as you don't extend this class, you don't have to implement any methods.

```
Abstract class AbstractClass extends ConcreteClass{
    public abstract void method();
}

class ConcreteClass {
    public void doSomething(){

    }
}
```

in the AbstractClass you don't have to implement the doSomething method, and in the ConcreteClass, you don't have to implement the method().
It would be better if you just try it yourself, and I recommend you to read this book
[http://www.amazon.com/SCJP-Certified-Programmer-Java-310-065/dp/0071591060](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071591060)

Thanks,
Khalil.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that, provided that the concrete class you extends is not final. And like all abstract classes, they cannot be instantiated.

An example use for this is if you want your inheritors to, for instance, reimplement some methods... Say:

```
public abstract class MustHaveEqualsAndHashCode()
{
    @Override
    public abstract int hashCode();

    @Override
    public abstract boolean equals(Object obj);
}
```

Note however that this is quite rare. Most of the time, it can be advantageously replaced with composition instead.